# Finding a prime field with n-th roots of unity

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-field

How can I find the smallest prime $p$, such that field $GF(p)$ has $n$-th roots of unity?

For example, I know that for $p=2^{256} - 351 \times 2^{32} + 1$ there exit roots of unity for $n=2^{32}$. But I don't know if there is a smaller $p$ that would have the same "order" for the roots of unity, or how to find smallest prime $p$ for a specific $n$.

If it makes things easier, for my purposes, $n$ can always be a power of $2$.

Comment: $1$ is always a $n$th root of unity, for any $n$, in any field. Also, how does this relate to cryptography?

Comment: @fkraiem: well, sometimes in ring lattices, we at times use the NFT algorithm to speed ring multiplies - that uses a large root of unity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find the smallest prime $p$, such that field $GF(p)$ has $n$-th roots of unity?

Any prime of the form $kn + 1$ has $n$-th roots of unity; we know this because the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (for prime $p$) is a cyclic group of order $p-1$, hence for all the factors of $p-1$, including $(p-1)/k$, it has elements of that order (at least, if you don't count values of $p$ which have $2^{31}$th roots of unity, but not elements of order $2^{32}$)

A quick search shows that $18 \cdot 2^{32} + 1 = 77309411329$ is the smallest prime of that form, hence that is your answer.

A quick computation shows $45467087722 ^ {2^{32}} \equiv 1 \pmod{77309411329}$, that is, it is a $2^{32}$th root of unity (and more specifically, it has order $2^{32}$)

Comment: Thank you! So, basically, I pick $n$ and then just try different values for $k$ until I get $kn+1$ that is a prime, right?

Comment: @irakliy: pretty much, yes.  Then, to find an element $e$ of order $n$, you pick a random $r$, compute $e = r^k \bmod p$, and then verify that $e^{n/2} \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$, if so, then $e$ is your element (you need extra checks if $n$ is not a power of 2)